# JQuery => How to make the code a library

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am finally finished with what I've started. I created a responsive lightbox slideshow!

But, I am kinda facing a problem. I want to make it a library...In other words, I want the code to apply to the html classes that I can add infinitely (Like all libraries do).

Thank you!

```js
var imageSliding = $('.box > .img');
        $('.lightbox').click(function() {
            $('.backdrop, .box').animate({
                'opacity': '.50'
            }, 300, 'linear');
            $('.box').animate({
                'opacity': '1.00'
            }, 300, 'linear');
            $('.backdrop, .box').css('display', 'block');
        });

        $('.close').click(function() {
            close_box();
        });

        $('.backdrop').click(function() {
            close_box();
        });

        function close_box() {
            $('.backdrop, .box').animate({
                'opacity': '0'
            }, 300, 'linear', function() {
                $('.backdrop, .box').css('display', 'none');
            });
        }

        /* Slider */
        var speed = 100;

        $(".prev").click(function() {
            var gallery = $(this).closest('.box').find("ul.gallery"),
                now = gallery.children(":visible"),
                last = gallery.children(":last"),
                prev = now.prev();
            prev = prev.index() == -1 ? last : prev;
            now.fadeOut(speed, function() {
                prev.fadeIn(speed);
            });
        });

        $(".next").click(function() {
            var gallery = $(this).closest('.box').find("ul.gallery"),
                now = gallery.children(":visible"),
                first = gallery.children(":first"),
                next = now.next();
            next = next.index() == -1 ? first : next;
            now.fadeOut(speed, function() {
                next.fadeIn(speed);
            });
        });

        $(".gallery li").click(function() {
            var first = $(this).parent().children(':first'),
                next = $(this).next();
            next = next.index() == -1 ? first : next;
            $(this).fadeOut(speed, function() {
                next.fadeIn(speed);
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: [How to Create a Basic Plugin](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See jQuery main Documentation for this: [basic-plugin-creation](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/)

Also TeamTreehouse has a good tutorial About this: [writing-your-own-jquery-plugins](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/writing-your-own-jquery-plugins)